# Android - Lollipop/Material Theme - 9 patch splash display incorrectly

Tags: android, nine-patch

My app's splash screen uses 9 patch png. Was working fine. Now I upgrade it to Lollipop/Material Theme (uses AppCompat and targetSDK="21") and the splash looks like following. Two black spots are there. Any idea?

[image]

It shouldn't have any black spots. This is the original 9 patch:

[image]

Comment: show your 9 patch and what it is suppose to look like

Comment: Why do you even need something like this to be a 9-patch?

Comment: So I don't have to have different sizes of images for different devices. Is it a bug on lollipop?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your result. Also, a centered no-dpi image would get the same result.

Comment: That means I have to make the splash screen activity white background. Also, no-dpi doesn't show best resolution on each device.

Answer (score 1):

This happens with Lollipop.

To resolve it, the Nine-path resources need the padding "optionals" lines. In this version, these lines are necessary all along the right hand and bottom sides of the 9 patch to get splash working without any weird gaps.

[Android nine patch - padding lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWiRj.png)

They didn't tell anything about this in the docs but this works for me.

You can read something about the padding lines [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)